# How can I organize my layouts in my Android manifest file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-manifest

Hi guys I'm new in Android Studio, I'm actually on an project and I was wondering how I can organize my layouts let me explain, I have three layouts and I don't know how to display the first then the second and the third in that order:
-Splash Screen
-principal
-mainActivity
Here is my Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.recipe">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".principal" />
        <activity android:name=".RecipeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hope I was clear and I know it's easy to do but as I said I'm new.
Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make the manifest file more readable by organizing it?

Comment: no @TheHungryAndroider when i run my app i want to display the splash Screen first then principal then the mainActivity with this configuration of android manifest it display the mainActivity directly

Comment: In that case, that is done from the code. Check @MohammadMoeinGolchin answer below to launch with the SplashScreen, but from there, you will have to create an Intent to launch your principal screen, and from the principal screen, you have to create another Intent to launch to MainActivity.

Comment: You can check my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.recipe">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".principal" />
        <activity android:name=".RecipeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Change your manifest to this. Your app will start from splash screen. After that it depends that you want to go to which activity. By using **intent** you can go from one activity to another one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.recipe">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".principal" />
    <activity android:name=".RecipeActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The rest of the intent and app navigation is your doing , good luck .